# Disable Autolink in ToastUi Editor

Tags: toast-ui-editor

How can I setup ToastUi Editor in wysiwyg-mode but disable the GFM-Autolink function (I do not wish the editor to recognise URLs and stuff on its own and translate them to markdown). I have tried

```
const editor=$('#editor').toastuiEditor({
      previewStyle: 'vertical',
      initialValue: text,
      initialEditType: 'wysiwyg',
      extendedAutolinks: false
});
```

Anyhow, the API tells me to pass an object to "extendedAutolinks", but I do not have an idea which. https://nhn.github.io/tui.editor/latest/ToastUIEditor

Comment: were you able to disable it in any way?

Comment: No, I did not find a solution and went to another editor.